# ML Modeling Recommendation for Predicting Snake Encounters in Historical Journey Data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, hidden-markov-model

I have a dataset consisting of historical journey data where individuals travel from point A to point B. During their journeys, they may encounter varying numbers of animal sightings, including snakes. The dataset includes attributes such as time, attribute_1, attribute_2, attribute_3, attribute_4, and a binary label indicating whether a snake was seen or not.

My objective is to create a website that can predict, based on a person's ID and their journey from point X to point Y, whether they are likely to encounter a snake during their next step. I want to choose the most suitable ML modeling approach for this task.

Considering the dynamic nature of the data, the need for real-time predictions, and the potential relevance of the previous snake sightings as additional information, I would like recommendations on which ML modeling techniques to explore. Additionally, I have additional attributes (attribute_1, attribute_2, etc.) that could potentially contribute to the prediction accuracy.

What ML modeling approaches would be most appropriate for this problem? Are there specific algorithms, architectures, or techniques that would be well-suited to handle this type of sequential prediction task?

Can the problem be solved by considering it as a time series classification problem and using the techniques such as LSTM RNN or HMM?

I would appreciate any insights, advice, or references to relevant research papers or tutorials that can help me make an informed decision.

P.S.
The example of the data structure:

| id | time/step | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | attribute_3 | attribute_4 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | b | j | 10 | 105 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | b | h | 12 | 45 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | b | g | 12 | 454 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | y | j | 4 | 54 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | y | m | 7 | 65 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | x | l | 6 | 76 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | x | r | 99 | 99 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | x | e | 88 | 8 | 0 |
| 3 | 9 | x | w | 65 | 45 | 0 |
| 3 | 10 | x | f | 44 | 56 | 1 |
| 3 | 11 | x | h | 33 | 45 | 0 |

As can be seen each person might encounter a different number of animals, but what we know this number wouldn't be greater than 25. It depends on from and to where he/she travels. Label 0 means he/she sees an animal but it is not a snake, and 1 shows he/she sees a snake in that certain time/step.

This prediction is important because in the live system if we predict that the person will see the snake in the next step of his/her journey then we can notify him/her beforehand.